# Computing Eigen Values and Eigen Vector using IronPython2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, ironpython, eigenvector, eigenvalue

This might be a frequent problem for IronPython users. But I am new to python.

I wish to compute Eigen Value and Eigen vector of around 50x50 matrix using IronPython2.7
I explored possibilities of using Numpy and Scipy, but they are not supported for IronPython.

Are there any better ways to achieve what I require?

Comment: Have a look at [Sho](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/19418d96-6e47-440f-b70d-9ad5c93a79b9/default.aspx). It supports numerical computations in IronPython.

Comment: @user1797612: you probably don't have experience with many of the tools you mention. Python is not good at performance in general, but using Numpy (and a number of other packages, mostly written in C and/or Fortran) makes Python very good at numerical computations.

Comment: @MuhammadAlkarouri for what it matters the standard python interpreter itself is written in C ( Cpython ), this is not the point that gives you performances. Python it's not a first choice for performance because of its design and internal mechanism. I have also tried myself and I think that any performance-demanding application it's simply not for Python; if you find Python fast enough I'm happy for you, but there are better alternatives.

Comment: @user1797612: Anyone who does any serious numerical work will tell you that Python with numpy blows away C#, and usually beats just about anything else short of hand-optimized Fortran (or sometimes C)—and it's a lot easier to use.

Comment: @abarnert i see no point in this discussion, i can't see how a slow language like python can be even faster than C, Lua can compete with C, Python really not.

Comment: @user1797612: Obviously evaluating one line of Python vs. C (e.g., `a * b` vs. `arraymult(a, b)`) is much higher… but compared to the cost of actually cross-multiplying two large arrays, it's so insignificant that it doesn't matter. If `numpy`'s `operator*` is 20% faster than C's `arraymult`, the total operation will be 19.9999% faster in Python than in C. If you really don't get this, you shouldn't be allowed to optimize anything.

Comment: @Tushar: Getting back on topic, have you tested Muhammad Alkarouri's suggestion of Sho? I've never used it, but it looks like it's worth trying. If it's good enough, ask him to write it as an answer and accept it; if it's not good enough, tell us why it doesn't fit the bill for you.

Comment: @abarnert@MuhammadAlkarouri: Sho does fit my requirement. Thanks a lot for your inputs. Can you please add it to answer?

Comment: @MuhammadAlkarouri: You should write an answer around your suggestion so Tushar can accept it. (Tushar, when you `@` two people in a single comment on SO, only the first one gets notified… kind of annoying. That's why I added this otherwise-useless comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sho for IronPython](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/19418d96-6e47-440f-b70d-9ad5c93a79b9/default.aspx) is a good environment by Microsoft that does provide what you want. I am glad it worked for you.

To quote the link itself

> Sho is a playground for data: a set of libraries and an interactive
>   environment for rapid prototyping, data analysis, and visualization.

The linear algebra classes in Sho do provide multiple functions for computing the eigenvalues, as shown in [the book of Sho](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/sho/documentation/sho2.0/TheBookofSho.html#_Toc282280647).